# The "Invite your friends and colleagues now" link in the email I got is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Got an email after accepting to be in Careers to invite friends. It seems the "Invite your friends and colleagues now" link in the email is broken.

Comment: What is the url that you are given?

Comment: Could you give us more information?  I took a look at the email we sent to your address and the URL appears to be correct: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitations.  Note that you need to be logged in to see the page.

Comment: I remember it dumping me off somewhere but it wasn't the login page. I just tried to replicate it but now it sends me to the login page. Must of been in a weird state. If I can reproduce it I'll let you know.

Comment: @DonnyV we've since fixed it to send you to login instead of a generic "Page not found" page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren't logged in, we were sending you to 404 Page Not Found instead of the login screen.  That has been fixed.